# Make dropdown menu appear on hover with a timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation, timeout

I recently made this simple navigation where you have a couple links that have a dropdown. First it was in CSS3 only but then I decided to add some jQuery to make the dropdown appear after a certain amount of time. (Most of the jQuery code is based on an answer given in another thread)

Basically, my issue is that I can't target the right element hovered, therefore when I hover a li element, all my dropdown  show up. I tried tweaking it as much as I could but I can't find the right piece of code.

Any reply is greatly appreciated!

My menu looks like this:

```
<ul id="generale">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 5</a></li>
                    </ul>     
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subitem 5</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
```

and my jQuery:

```
var navTimers = [];  
            $( "#generale > li" ).hover(
                function () {  
                    var id = jQuery.data( this );  
                    var $this = $( this ); 

                    navTimers[id] = setTimeout( function() {  
                        $('#generale ul').fadeIn(200); 
                        navTimers[id] = "";  
                    }, 300 );  
                },  
                function () {  
                    var id = jQuery.data( this );  
                    if ( navTimers[id] != "" ) {  
                        clearTimeout( navTimers[id] );  
                    } else {  
                        $('#generale ul').fadeOut(200);
                    }  
                }  
            );
```

Comment: why don't you just add a class to the li's you need to drop, and target that class. Actually after looking at your code, the show and hide of your menu is targeted on the ul not li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fadeIn and fadeOut functions are currently targeting all `ul`s within the `#generale` element.

Try changing

```
$('#generale ul').fadeIn(200);
```

to

```
$this.find('ul').fadeIn(200);
```

and

```
$('#generale ul').fadeOut(200);
```

to

```
$this.find('ul').fadeOut(200); // you'll also have to define $this = $(this)
```